# XSLT to replace XML element value

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to use XSLT and replace xml element value by another element if second element value is not empty. In example below I need to replace *Item* tag value by *ItemMaster-CustomChar10* tag value only if it exists

```
<WmsShippingResultOutSiEs>
    <RecordId>6</RecordId>
    <ShipmentTransactionId>146</ShipmentTransactionId>
    <OutboundOrder>ERIC_1</OutboundOrder>
    <WmsShippingResultLineOutSiEs>
        <Line>
            <RecordId>6</RecordId>
            <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
            <Item>BMS9</Item>
            <ItemMaster-CustomChar10>BMS9ALIAS</ItemMaster-CustomChar10>
            <WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>143</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
            </WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <RecordId>6</RecordId>
            <ShipmentLineSequence>2</ShipmentLineSequence>
            <Item>BMS10</Item>
            <ItemMaster-CustomChar10/>
            <WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>144</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>2</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>145</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
            </WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
        </Line>
    </WmsShippingResultLineOutSiEs>
</WmsShippingResultOutSiEs>
```

I'm expecting to have a result like

```
<WmsShippingResultOutSiEs>
    <RecordId>6</RecordId>
    <ShipmentTransactionId>146</ShipmentTransactionId>
    <OutboundOrder>ERIC_1</OutboundOrder>
    <WmsShippingResultLineOutSiEs>
        <Line>
            <RecordId>6</RecordId>
            <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
            <Item>BMS9ALIAS</Item>
            <ItemMaster-CustomChar10>BMS9ALIAS</ItemMaster-CustomChar10>
            <WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>143</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
            </WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <RecordId>6</RecordId>
            <ShipmentLineSequence>2</ShipmentLineSequence>
            <Item>BMS10</Item>
            <ItemMaster-CustomChar10/>
            <WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>1</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>144</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                    <ShipmentLineSequence>2</ShipmentLineSequence>
                    <ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>145</ShipmentLineDetailTransactionId>
                </Line>
            </WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs>
        </Line>
    </WmsShippingResultLineOutSiEs>
</WmsShippingResultOutSiEs>
```

All other elements need shouldn't be affected.
Is it possible to do it recursivly?

My XSLT code below doesn't work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:for-each select="//WmsShippingResultLineDetailOutSiEs/Lines">
    <xsl:variable name="host_item" select="ItemMaster-CustomChar10"/>
    <xsl:if test="ItemMaster-CustomChar10 !=''">
        <Item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$host_item"/>
        </Item>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As with most XML to XML transformations, I would suggest to use the identity transformation as the starting point and then add a template for the element(s) you want to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line[ItemMaster-CustomChar10[normalize-space()]]/Item">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="../ItemMaster-CustomChar10"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsJ